# present perfect continuous for an action recently stopped

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

The present perfect continuous can be used for an action that has just stopped, but has a present result, for example: I have been gardening (my hands are covered in soil) or it has been raining (the streets are wet). My question is: if there has been a party which has finished but there are still empty glasses and bottles everywhere, is it possible to say "they have been having a party"? The party has finished but there is a result in the present.

Comment: There has been a party here, you can tell from the mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That would be a correct use of the present perfect continuous, for the reasons that you give.

Comment: Seeing the mess. Can I either use present perfect or present perfect continuous:(1) They have been having a party there.  (2) There has been a party here.?